# passing parameter and retain value after function call in python

Tags: python

I believe this is a simple question but still want to get a quick and clear answer to my case:

```
def get_query_history(idx, url, archive_location):
        idx = idx + 1
    return idx    # I meant to return the idx's value (end up 1000 for every call) and used it in the next loop in main

main:

    idx = 1 
    while current <= end_date:
        with open(archive_location, 'a') as the_archive:
            get_query_history(idx, url, archive_location)  # I want to increase the idx every time I call the function
```

Apparently this is not the way I should take in python, can anyone enlighten me?

Comment: Are you talking about the concept of static variables? You can just define `index` as global, then only change the global variable and not redefine it or pass it around

Comment: Since you're returning `idx` increased value, just store it back in the 'main' scope: `idx = get_query_history(idx, url, archive_location)`

Comment: Also, don't use `with open` context manager anew for every `while` loop iteration. use `with open...: while...`

Comment: Finally, your using `idx` as a variable in your global scope. no need to pass it to or return it from the function. You can use it once the loop is over

Comment: Thank you @zwer, it works, how do I select this as the answer? And thanks to all replies.

Comment: What is wrong with adding `idx += 1` after the function call?

Answer (score 0):

Here, I'll post it as an answer but I'll expand a bit.

Since you're returning `idx` increased value, just store it back in the 'main' scope:

```
idx = 1 
while current <= end_date:
    with open(archive_location, 'a') as the_archive:
        idx = get_query_history(idx, url, archive_location)
    # make sure you update your `current` ;)
```

In some languages you have an option to pass a variable to a function by reference in such a way that the function can change its value so you wouldn't need to return your value. Python kind of passes by reference, but since simple values are unmutable whenever you try to set its value in your function the *reference* to the passed value gets overwritten.

This doesn't apply to encapsulated objects, tho, so you could encapsulate your `idx` in a list and then pass it as a list. In that case you wouldn't need return at all:

```
def get_query_history(idx, url, archive_location):
    idx[0] += 1
    # do whatever else

# in your main:

idx = [1]  # encapsulate the value in a list
while current <= end_date:
    with open(archive_location, 'a') as the_archive:
        get_query_history(idx, url, archive_location)  # notice, no return capture
    # make sure you update your `current` ;)
```

But generally, if you can return the value there is no need for these shenanigans, it's just to demonstrate that a function can modify the passed arguments under certain conditions.

And, finally, if you really want to force pass-by-reference behavior, you can totally hack Python to do even that, [**check this**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45113210/7553525) (and never use it in production!) ;)