# how can i refer to instance name in the class?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class

in this code:

```
class X:
    def __init__(self, y=None):
        self.y = y
        self.z = []
        try:
            y.z.append(self)
        except:
            pass

a = X()
b = X(a)
c = X(a)

print(a.z)
```

I want to print [b, c] but it prints something like this

```
out: <__main__.x object at 0x01775E70>, <__main__.x object at 0x01775E90>]
```

how i can fix it?

Comment: Please take a look at the code in your question and fix the indentation

Comment: What's there to fix? That's how python represents `b` and `c`.

Comment: i want to it sends back me just right [b,c] not the addresses of them

Comment: `b` and `c` are objects (instances of X), how do you expect for Python to know how you want them represented? If you want a custom representation, read on [`__repr__()`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__repr__) and [`__str__()`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__str__) _magic_ methods.

Comment: Do not use code as data. If you want your objects to have a `.name` attribute, then give them a `.name` attribute.

Answer (score 1):

Impossible*. Names refer to values unidirectionally. You cannot go from a value to a name. Consider many names refering to the same value, e.g. `a = b = 1`. What would be the *true* name of the value `1`? There is none, all names are equal.

*without inspecting the source code. And as I said, what should happen to how `a.z` is displayed if you then assign `c = b`? What you are trying to do is fruitless and if you really need it you have a design issue.

Comment: A nitpick - not impossible but very impractical (and mostly useless). The assignment can be backtracked by inspecting the previous frame to pick up the name it's being assigned to - sort of a simplified version of [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45113210/7553525) without the back-assignment. It's still very, very not recommended.

Comment: i know that but in this case i want those names, what can i do for that?

Comment: @zwer satisfied? :)

Comment: @papay you can't in any way that would make sense.

Comment: @timgeb - Very 

Answer (score 0):

If you want `print` to display a text for an object, you need to implement the [__str__](https://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/datamodel.html#object.__str__) method:

```
class X:
    def __init__(self, name, y=None):
        self.name = name
        self.y = y
        self.z = []
        try:
            y.z.append(self)
        except:
            pass

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.name


a = X("a")
b = X("b", a)
c = X("c", a)

print(a.z)
```

Or did you want print to use the name of the reference of the object?

Comment: this code also print "[<__main__.X object at 0x01777D70>, <__main__.X object at 0x01777D90>]"

Comment: Fixed it, list.__str__ display the object inside the list using their __repr__method