# Python - imported function doesn't modify local variable

Tags: python

I have a python script (myscript.py)that  contains a number of funtions, and a global variable called 'resultsdict' (an empty dictionary).    I want to reuse one of those functions (myfunc).

myfunc takes a single input (input), creates a dictionary (tempdict), and then updates resultsdict (key = input, value =  tempdict).     I generally use this function by looping through a list, calling each member of the list as input.

```
resultsdict = {}
mylist = [1,2,3]
for x in mylist:
    myfunc(x)
print(resultsdict)
{1:{dict of results-1},2:{dict of results-2},3:{dict of results-3}}
```

I want to reuse myfunc in a second script (script2.py).    script2.py also contains a global variable called resultsdict.   When I import myfunc to script2 and run it , the resultsdict variable isn't updated.

```
from myscript import myfunc
resultsdict = {}
mylist = [1,2,3]
for x in mylist:
    myfunc(x)
print(resultsdict)
{}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: but you are not returning nothing from myfunc, plus inside of it you are re declaring resultsdict = {} so every time u call the function it set-up resultsdict = {}. could u pls show all the code and give an example of expected result?

Comment: `myfunc` will update whatever `resultsdict` variable is in *its scope*. This is simply not how it works. You either want to use a class, or explicit accept and return values.

Comment: It's correct that myfunc doesn't return anything.     It's not correct that everytime I call the function it set-up resultsdict = {} - that assignment is done in the body of the script, rather than within the function

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Modifying function arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45111055/modifying-function-arguments)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

import the resultsdict too. 
Then if you want make a copy.

```
from myscript import myfunc, resultsdict

mylist = [1,2,3]
for x in mylist:
    myfunc(x)
print(resultsdict)
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you modify `resultsdict` from global scope in your `myfunc`.
Try change this behavior to transfer `resultsdict` via attributes:

```
def myfync(x, resultsdict):
...
```

or add line about that `resultsdict` is from global scope(worse way):

```
def myfync(x):
    global resultsdict
...
```

and in any way modify mutable object in some function is bad way.

Answer (score 0):

in your for statement, you use "list" but in the line before that, you declare "mylist" !! 
**Note**: there is no "list" and thats why your code does not work.

Edit your for statement like below:

```
for x in my mylist:
    ...
```

Comment: that's a typo in my pseudocode.    Updated original post to fix